# ACF Upload Image in repeater from front-end with custom form? - add_post_meta()

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, post-meta, advanced-custom-fields

I want to upload images in the ACF repeater. That repeater means the gallery of page.
Point is to create post in custom post type using **add_post_meta()** method.

Here I have the form :

```
<input type="file"  class="custom-file-input" id="customFile" multiple accept="image/x-png,image/gif,image/jpeg" name="gallery[]">
```

Form method is **POST** and form have `enctype="multipart/form-data"` attribute.

In the accept file where I need to process request and income:

```
$estate_gallery = $_FILES['gallery']; //array of images, I have above in input name="gallery[]"
```

Well, in ACF I have created Repeater of gallery images, to create fields (in my case subfields) I used [this example](https://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/acf-repeater-filed-in-add_post_meta/).

```
$repeater_field = 'repeater'; //with my keys and names
$repeater_key = 'field_5443d4e2dd4e4';
$sub_field = 'sub_field';
$sub_field_key = 'field_5443d4e2dd4e5';

$count = count($values); // here in my case is $estate_gallery
if ($count) {
  // the db value stored in the db for a repeater is
  // the number if rows in the repeater
  add_post_meta($post_id, $repeater_field, $count, true);
  add_post_meta($post_id, '_'.$repeater_field, $repeater_key, true);
  for ($i=0; $i<$count; $i++) {
    // the actual field name in the DB is a concatenation of
    // the repeater field name, the index of the current row
    // and the sub field name, with underscores added
    $sub_field_name = $repeater_field.'_'.$i.'_'.$sub_field;
    add_post_meta($post_id, $sub_field_name, $values[$i], false);
    add_post_meta($post_id, '_'.$sub_field_name, $sub_field_key, false);
  }
}
```

And that works very well, numbers of subfields in the repeater are equal to image number in input.

But I can't see images uploaded...

I suppose images from input must be uploaded in media and connected with repeater field? How do that?

Thanks. o/